# How do I get both my image and button to display?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout, flowlayout

Currently, the problem I am trying to solve is how I get both my image and button to show up.

When I have the following line in the code the image shows up but when I remove it my image doesn't display but the button does:
`setLayout (new FlowLayout()) ;`

[without the line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XWXA.png)

[with the line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDrrP.png)

Images for example ^

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Panel extends JFrame {
    private ImageIcon FirstPageImage;
    private JLabel FirstPageLabel;
    private JLayeredPane SignupButtonLayer;
    private JButton Button;

public Panel(){
    setLayout (new FlowLayout()) ;
    FirstPageImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("FirstPageAnimationUsing.gif"));
    FirstPageLabel = new JLabel(FirstPageImage);
    FirstPageImage.setImage(FirstPageImage.getImage().getScaledInstance(343,820,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    add(FirstPageLabel);

    Button = new JButton();
    SignupButtonLayer = new JLayeredPane();

    Button.setOpaque(true);
    Button.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    Button.setBounds(94,617,159,82);

    SignupButtonLayer.add(Button, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    add(SignupButtonLayer);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Panel gui = new Panel();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setTitle("Reminder App");
        gui.setSize(360,850);

    }
}
```

Comment: **Meta Question:** What layout does the frame use for the content pane when code **does not** set a flow layout? Note that at the moment you seem to be 'programming by magic'. Consult the docs, learn how to use the various layouts. It is not welcomed to come here for every GUI made (probably several times for each), and many questions can be solved by doing the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).

- You need to give the `JLayeredPane` a preferred size. Since your `JLayeredPane` contains only a single `JButton`, that size should be big enough to display the entire `JButton`.
- The arguments to method `setBounds` – that you call on `Button` –  are relative to its container, i.e. `SignupButtonLayer`. Setting the *x* to 94 and the *y* to 617 means that `Button` is placed **outside** of the bounds of `SignupButtonLayer`. Hence you don't see it. In the below code, I set *x* and *y* both to 0 (zero) so that the top, left corner of `Button` aligns with the top, left corner of `SignupButtonLayer`.
- No need to explicitly call method `setOpaque(true)` for `Button` since that is the default, anyway.
- Either call `pack()` – which is usually preferred – or `setSize()` but don't call both.
- `setVisible(true)` should be called only once your GUI is completely built. In the below code I call it after calling `pack()` and `setTitle()`.
- I suggest that you try to adhere to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).
- I also suggest that try not to name your classes the same as classes in the JDK. I am referring to [Panel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Panel.html).

The below code simply resolves your problem, i.e. displaying both the image and the button together – while using `FlowLayout` for the [content pane of the] `JFrame`. Notice that the preferred size of `SignupButtonLayer` is slightly larger than the size arguments in method `setBounds`.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;

public class Panel extends JFrame {
    private ImageIcon FirstPageImage;
    private JLabel FirstPageLabel;
    private JLayeredPane SignupButtonLayer;
    private JButton Button;

    public Panel() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        FirstPageImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("FirstPageAnimationUsing.gif"));
        FirstPageLabel = new JLabel(FirstPageImage);
        FirstPageImage.setImage(FirstPageImage.getImage().getScaledInstance(343, 820, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        add(FirstPageLabel);

        Button = new JButton();
        SignupButtonLayer = new JLayeredPane();
        SignupButtonLayer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 90));
//        Button.setOpaque(true);
        Button.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        Button.setBounds(0, 0, 159, 82);

        SignupButtonLayer.add(Button, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        add(SignupButtonLayer);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Panel gui = new Panel();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setTitle("Reminder App");
//        gui.setSize(360, 850);
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: So i tried out your code and its working for me but now the other part of this is that I want the button to be on top of the sign up part of the image. How do I go about doing that? 
[link](https://imgur.com/a/S8wuOtE) example in the image @Abra